# How would I return n number of artists for a given genre

Tags: java

Question in the title: I have a class that that maps some artists with their corresponding genre. Reads from a text file with lines containting "artist genre" e.g. "ACDC Rock". I'm having trouble with the getArtists(String genre, int n) class in particular. How can I return n number of artists in a specific genre? I'm assuming I have to create a for loop from 0 to n, then if the map contains that genre, return the artists somehow, but I'm confused on how to do it. Here's what I've tried:

```
 public String getArtists(String genre, int n)
{   
   for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
       if (map.containsValue(genre)){
          
       }
  }
   return "";   
}
```

Here's the rest of the class:

```
public class Artists {

Map<String,String> map;

public Artists()
{
    map = new TreeMap<>();
}

public boolean readArtists(String textFile)
{
     Scanner file, lineScan;
     boolean success = true;
     try
     {
        file = new Scanner(new File(textFile));
        while (file.hasNext())
        {
           String line = file.nextLine();
           String[] parts = line.split(" ");
           map.put(parts[0].toUpperCase().replace('_',' '), parts[1]);
        }         
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
     {
        success = false;
     }
     return success;
} 

public void addArtist (String artist, String genre) 
{
     map.put(artist.toUpperCase(), genre);
}

public void display()
{
     System.out.printf("%-30s %s\n", "ARTIST", "GENRE");
     System.out.printf("%-30s %s\n", "------", "-----");
     Set<String> artists = map.keySet();
     for (String artist: artists)
        System.out.printf("%-30s %s\n", artist, map.get(artist));
}

 /**
       Returns a formatted list of at most n artists of the given genre.
      @param genre the genre of artists to be included 
      @param n the maximum number of artists to be included
      @return a list containing at most n artists of the given genre
 */
 public String getArtists(String genre, int n)
{   
   for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
       if (map.containsValue(genre)){
          
       }
    }
     return "";
 
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {    
   Artists artists = new Artists();
   artists.readArtists("artists30.txt");
   artists.addArtist("ACDC", "Rock");
    artists.display();
  System.out.println(artists.getArtists("Rock", 10));  
  System.out.println(artists.getArtists("Country", 10)); 
 }      
}
```

Comment: Surely you want to return a `List<String>`, not one string?

Comment: @BillCosby Please don't fundamentally change your question once it received answers. It invalidates the time others spent on answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the entire map, then add the key (artist) to a list when you find a matching genre

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    if (v.equals(genre) && result.size() < n) result.add(k);
});
return result;
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use an iterator... You can use a StringBuilder instead of a List, sure, but the method comment explicit says "return a list". You could have a separate method that formats the list to a string

Comment: Sure, you can replace `map.forEach` with a loop over `Iterator<Map.Entry>`, and `List` with `StringBuilder`. The logic is still the same

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a mapping from genre to a list of artists instead of a map of artist to genre, something like that:

```java
Map<String,List<String>> map;
public void addArtist (String artist, String genre) 
{
  map.computeIfAbsent(genre, genre -> new LinkedList<>()).add(artist);
}
public List<String> getArtists(String genre, int n) {
  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>(n);
  List<String> mapList = map.get(genre);
  if (mapList == null)
    return result;
  for (int i = 0; i < n && i < mapList.size(); ++i)
    result.add(mapList.get(i));
}
```

If you want to keep your map, you also can do something like:

```java
public List<String> getArtists(String genre, int n) {
  return map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> genre.equals(entry.getValue())).limit(n).map(entry -> entry.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

To answer your comment, if you want to return a single String, you can do something like that:

```java
public String getArtists(String genre, int n) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> genre.equals(entry.getValue())).limit(n).forEach(entry -> result.append(entry.getKey());
  return result;
}
```

Or, because I guess you are beginner, and may be not used with streams, a simple way, not so optimized, but may be more comprehensible:

```java
public String getArtists(String genre, int n) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  int count = 0;
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (count >= n)
      break; // if we already reach the limit n, stop the loop
    if (!genre.equals(entry.getValue())
      continue; // if this is not an artist of the genre we are looking for, skip it
    if (result.length() > 0)
      result.append(", "); // if this is not the first, add a comma so it is prettier
    result.append(entry.getKey()); // append the name of the artist
    count++; // increment the counter
  }
  return result;
}
```

Many ways :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making a class for Artists that holds the info like so:

```
    class ArtistInfo{
        String name;
        String genre;

        ArtistInfo(String name, String genre) {
            this.name = name;
            this.genre = genre;
        }
    }
```

and then you can perform lots of actions like filter on the array list like so:

```
    ArrayList<ArtistInfo> ai = new ArrayList<>();
    ai.add(new ArtistInfo("ACDC", "Rock"));
    Stream<ArtistInfo> filteredList = ai.stream().filter(n -> n.genre.equals("Rock"));
```

and then get the count:

```
    long count = filteredList.count();
```

`count` is the number of artists with the genre "Rock".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. We scan all the value and compare every value with genre and return first n result.

```
public String getArtists(String genre, int n)
{
    List<String> artists = new ArrayList<>();
    map.forEach((key,value)-> {
        
        if(value.equals(genre)){
            if(artists.size() < n) artists.add(key);
        }
    });
    StringBuilder artistsAsString = new StringBuilder();
    for(String artist : artists){
        artistsAsString.append(artist).append(" ");
    }
    return artistsAsString.toString();

}
```